# Crystal Reports - Two identical reports - one works, the other generates a parameter error

Tags: crystal-reports, report, parameter-passing

I have two reports, completely identical (one saved from the other).
One is working perfectly and the other generates the **attached** error. I have noticed that when I go to run the report, both of the parameter screens have different default values (as circled in the **attached** - the first parameter screen is the report that works). I am not sure if this has anything to do with it, but they should be exactly the same as they are identical. I am at a loss as to what is going on... is anyone able to shed some light? Thanks in advance.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I seemed to have solved the problem.

I have deleted and re-saved the report as 'test' and it seems to be working.

I had previously deleted the report with the error and re-saved it but as the same name as previous - not sure if this was the issue.

Comment: Very possible.  I had a similar issue before.  Esp. if you had both reports open at the same time.